# foreach is not looping over element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, foreach

I have a loop on rxDetails if any rxNumber matched with data add new field `payAmount` if not return item as it is , so in my below `forEach` its not returning 5 elements its always missing rxNumber `15131503` in return , any idea what is implemented wrong here ? what i noticed is forEach is skipping loop on one of the element not sure why.

data

```
const rxDetails = [
  {
    "drugName": "TRILIPIX 135MG CPDR",
    "rxNumber": "15131523",
    "lldIndicator": "N"
  },
  {
    "drugName": "GILENYA 0.5MG CAPS",
    "rxNumber": "15131519",
    "lldIndicator": "N"
  },
  {
    "drugName": "JAKAFI 5MG TABS",
    "rxNumber": "15131503",
    "lldIndicator": "Y"
  },
  {
    "drugName": "FENOFIBRATE MICRONIZED 134MG CAPS",
    "rxNumber": "15131510",
    "lldIndicator": "N"
  },
  {
    "drugName": "LIPITOR 10MG TABS",
    "rxNumber": "15131506",
    "lldIndicator": "N"
  },
  {
    "drugName": "KEFLEX 750MG CAPS",
    "rxNumber": "15131522",
    "lldIndicator": "N"
  }
]

const data = [{
        "drugName": "TRILIPIX 135MG CPDR",
        "rxNumber": "15131523",
        "lldIndicator": "N",
        "payAmount": "10"
    },
    {
        "drugName": "GILENYA 0.5MG CAPS",
        "rxNumber": "15131519",
        "lldIndicator": "N",
        "payAmount": "8"
    },
    {
        "drugName": "METFORMIN",
        "rxNumber": "15425789",
        "lldIndicator": "Y",
        "payAmount": "0.50"
    },
    {
        "drugName": "FENOFIBRATE MICRONIZED 134MG CAPS",
        "rxNumber": "15131510",
        "lldIndicator": "N",
        "payAmount": "2.56"
    },
    {
        "drugName": "LIPITOR 10MG TABS",
        "rxNumber": "15131506",
        "lldIndicator": "N",
        "payAmount": "7.76"
    },
    {
        "drugName": "KEFLEX 750MG CAPS",
        "rxNumber": "15131522",
        "lldIndicator": "N",
        "payAmount": "17.88"
    }
]
```

main.ts

```
private getDrugsLastPrice(rxDetails: any, data: any) {
        let isDrugFound: boolean = false;
        const drugsArray: any = [];
        rxDetails.forEach((item: any) => {
            for (const element of data) {
                    if (item.rxNumber === element.rxNumber) {
                        isDrugFound = true;
                        const singleDrug = {
                            rxNumber: item.rxNumber,
                            lldIndicator: item.lldIndicator,
                            drugName: item.drugName,
                            payAmount: element.payAmount
                        };
                        drugsArray.push(singleDrug);
                    }

             }
            if (!isDrugFound) {
                drugsArray.push(item);
            }

        });

        return drugsArray;

    }

getDrugsLastPrice(rxDetails,data);
```

expected output

```
[{
        "drugName": "TRILIPIX 135MG CPDR",
        "rxNumber": "15131523",
        "lldIndicator": "N",
        "payAmount": "10"
    },
    {
        "drugName": "GILENYA 0.5MG CAPS",
        "rxNumber": "15131519",
        "lldIndicator": "N",
        "payAmount": "8"
    },
    {
        "drugName": "JAKAFI 5MG TABS",
        "rxNumber": "15131503",
        "lldIndicator": "Y"
    },
    {
        "drugName": "FENOFIBRATE MICRONIZED 134MG CAPS",
        "rxNumber": "15131510",
        "lldIndicator": "N",
        "payAmount": "2.56"
    },
    {
        "drugName": "LIPITOR 10MG TABS",
        "rxNumber": "15131506",
        "lldIndicator": "N",
        "payAmount": "7.76"
    },
    {
        "drugName": "KEFLEX 750MG CAPS",
        "rxNumber": "15131522",
        "lldIndicator": "N",
        "payAmount": "17.88"
    }
]
```

Comment: but if its not found i am still pushing that element tp drugsArray based on boolean `isDrugFound` becauase if rsNumber does not match i still have to return that element witout `payAmount` field

Comment: works fine for me... https://jsfiddle.net/u5qw2Ltp/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue that you have is that you needed to set the declaration of `isDrugFound` within the `forEach` loop. Once it's set to *true*, it **stays** *true* and that is the issue.

I simplified your code so you don't need the boolean.

Using Array#map, Array#find, spread syntax and destructuring.

```js
const rxDetails=[{"drugName":"TRILIPIX 135MG CPDR","rxNumber":"15131523","lldIndicator":"N"},{"drugName":"GILENYA 0.5MG CAPS","rxNumber":"15131519","lldIndicator":"N"},{"drugName":"JAKAFI 5MG TABS","rxNumber":"15131503","lldIndicator":"Y"},{"drugName":"FENOFIBRATE MICRONIZED 134MG CAPS","rxNumber":"15131510","lldIndicator":"N"},{"drugName":"LIPITOR 10MG TABS","rxNumber":"15131506","lldIndicator":"N"},{"drugName":"KEFLEX 750MG CAPS","rxNumber":"15131522","lldIndicator":"N"}]
const data=[{"drugName":"TRILIPIX 135MG CPDR","rxNumber":"15131523","lldIndicator":"N","payAmount":"10"},{"drugName":"GILENYA 0.5MG CAPS","rxNumber":"15131519","lldIndicator":"N","payAmount":"8"},{"drugName":"METFORMIN","rxNumber":"15425789","lldIndicator":"Y","payAmount":"0.50"},{"drugName":"FENOFIBRATE MICRONIZED 134MG CAPS","rxNumber":"15131510","lldIndicator":"N","payAmount":"2.56"},{"drugName":"LIPITOR 10MG TABS","rxNumber":"15131506","lldIndicator":"N","payAmount":"7.76"},{"drugName":"KEFLEX 750MG CAPS","rxNumber":"15131522","lldIndicator":"N","payAmount":"17.88"}]

const res = rxDetails.map(item=>{
  const d = data.find(({rxNumber})=>rxNumber===item.rxNumber);
  return d ? {...item, payAmount: d.payAmount} : {...item};
});

console.log("Number of elements: " + res.length);
console.log("Number with payAmount prop: " + res.filter(o=>o.payAmount !== undefined).length);
console.log("Number without payAmount prop:" + res.filter(o=>o.payAmount === undefined).length);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: trying to write your code in `const filteredArray = shipment.rxDetails.map((item: any) => {
            const d = data.find((rxNumber: any) => rxNumber === item.rxNumber);
            return d ? {...item, payAmount: d.payAmount} : {...item};
        });` but its returning data.find rxNumber undefined

Comment: for this use case i have only one object in rxDetails and data has that object with rxNumber property and it is matched with data

Comment: there is no error it is not matching the element and returning item without payAmount even though object is matched i am getting this on find `d: undefined data: Array(15) item: Object {
  "drugName": "JAKAFI 5MG TABS",
  "rxNumber": "15131503",
  "lldIndicator": "Y"
}`

Comment: @hussain well that's completely normal. You do not provide a payamount for rxNumber "15131503" in your data array, so no pay amount will appear.

Comment: @hussain if you wish I can set a payamount to 0 or -1 if it doesn't exist.

Comment: no thats the logic i wanted to implement if item is not matched that should pushed to array as it is without payAmount field. it rxDetails has 5 items one does not match output should still have 5 results one without payAmount.

Comment: @hussain and that is exactly what my script does no?

Comment: yeah but if item matched it should add payAmount that is not happening with your script not sure why it could be i am converting syntax to meet tsLint error

Comment: @hussain in the input you provide, you have 6 elements. In your data array, you have 6 elements where one of them (rxNumber: 15425789) does not exist in rxDetails. My final solution has 6 elements, where 5 have a payAmount and 1 does not  (rxNumber: 15131503) and rxNumber: 15425789 is excluded from the final result. The output I provide is exactly the one you provided in your question no?

Comment: found the issue it should be like  find.(element => element.rxNumber === data.rxNumber the way i change code

Answer (score 0):

You're never resetting `isDrugFound` in your `forEach` loop. Once it finds a match, the next iteration will still have `isDrugFound` set to true, so it won't be pushed, unless it also happens to be in the data array. In fact, once one data match is found, *only elements that are in the data array will be pushed.*

Comment: ok what is the fix here if i also want to push that is not matched

Comment: You need to reset `isDrugFound` to false at the beginning of your `forEach` loop. In fact, I would *declare* it there as well, so that you're guaranteed to only be using it as a boolean for one specific `rxDetails` element at a time, not re-using old (and incorrect) values.

Comment: Also my condition outside for of loop if its not found item should pushed because boolean is false

Comment: That's fine. It's outside the `for...of` loop, but it's still *inside* the `forEach` loop, which is the important part.